# Efficiently loop through a multidimensional array and output something different on duplicate values

Tags: php, arrays, performance

How to loop through a multidimensional array and on subarrays that have  the same value with other subarrays echo all of them there. This should be done without looping every time through the whole array. I'm looking for something better than O n squared.

```
$bigArray = [
  ["value" => $someValue, "importantValue" => $importantValue, "value_1" => $someValue],
  ["value" => $someValue, "importantValue" => $importantValue, "value_1" => $someValue],
  ["value" => $someValue, "importantValue" => $importantValue, "value_1" => $someValue]    
]

foreach($bigArray as $item){
  if($item[importantValue] has duplicates that can be all the way at the end of the parent array){
    echo "these are duplicates:". all the duplicates of that value here
    echo "duplicate 1: ".$item["value"].$item["importantValue"]
  } else {
    echo $item["value"].$item["importantValue"]
  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot have duplicate keys in php arrays. The value key will always be overwritten with the last occurring value key.

Comment: @Yolo I don't have duplicate keys in my example. I have an array of arrays and each subarray has different values. But another subarray can have the same value at the end of the parent array.

Comment: Each of your subarrays has two "value" keys.

Comment: @miken32 that is just an example to illustrate that there are more values. my bad, should have inserted _1. the important key is  importantValue